# Why are all columns of datatable (data.table) converted automatically to character vector [R]

Tags: r, data.table

I have created the datatable as follows:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table( a = c(1,2,3)
                ,b = c("f", "g", "c")
               )
```

It is supposed to have column data types: "integer", "character" but the output is *"character", "character"*:

```
 apply(x,2,class)

> apply(x,2,class)
       a           b  
"character" "character"
```

The same issue is with dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame( a = as.numeric(1)
                ,b = as.character("d")
               )
```

Could anyone make a hint about the root of the issue? it looks quite a weird but i have found no similar cases. I have never had such a case before.

**Session Info** is as follows:

> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Ukrainian_Ukraine.utf8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.14.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1    cli_3.6.1         rsconnect_1.1.1   tools_4.2.1       rstudioapi_0.15.0 lifecycle_1.0.4
[7] rlang_1.1.2

Comment: When you use `apply()` is coerces your input to a matrix. A matrix can only contain one data type so everything is coerced to a character in this case. You should really avoid using `apply()` on data.frames or data.tables. `sapply(x, class)` will return the expected values. Why are you trying to use `apply`?